# Free OPC server for simulated values

Tags: simulation, simulator, opc

I am developing an OPC client and need a free OPC server that can both simulate values ​​and set values static. Is there such a server freely available?

Comment: Did you search around? It looks like there's a lot of resources available. https://www.google.com/webhp?#q=opc+simulation

Comment: Of course I have searched. Have tried several, but the servers I've found are just demo versions that stop working after a while. not interesting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use Matrikon OPC explorer

you can download it for free, just need to register, it can simulate server and client on the same machine and also access servers remotely, i tested it on several OS along with several OPC servers.

[here](https://www.matrikonopc.com/downloads/176/software/index.aspx)

I am developing OPC client->server->device Emulator (C++)

Comment: How do I get the values ​​change over time, so that it is not just static values​​?

Comment: download script runner [here](http://j2eeps.cern.ch/wikis/display/EN/OPC+Testbench) and build scripts with groovy. notepad++ have text makeup for it and netBeans have some kind of integration for groovy too.

Answer (score 4):

Check out Prosys OPC Simulation Server. It does exactly what you need.

http://prosysopc.com/opc-downloads.php

Comment: Note that is an UA server (as opposed to the earlier Windows DCOM based OPC standard).

Comment: The simulation options are limited. You can have a programmable sine wave generator, square wave, up/down counter etc. But a simple read/write "register" style variable cannot be configured somehow.

Comment: Actually, I was referring to the Classic Simulation Server. Prosys OPC has both: OPC UA and OPC (Classic) Simulation Server. In the Classic server, you find different waveforms and data types and also Static variables to which you can read and write. The OPC UA Simulation Server has also a fixed set of variables for reading and writing (under StaticData), plus a configurable set of simulated variables.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.opcconnect.com/freesrv.php

i use [Kepware Server](http://www.kepware.com/kepserverex/) ,it restart every 2H, but for testing, is not a problem. Also, you can connect a PLC. In Matrikon you also can do it, but with more limitations..

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [www.opcfoundation.org](http://www.opcfoundation.org) website, you can find tools for creating OPC clients and servers. I don't remember specifically which ones, but some of these come with 'simulation servers' so that you can test your code.